# Does Stored Procedure works with NHibernate to return out parameter/ref_cursor or I need to Write Function to this

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures

Does Stored Procedure works with NHibernate to return out parameter/ref_cursor or I need to Write Function to this.Because it is working with function not with Stored Proc

@Diego:  **Mapping File**
 < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   < hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
     < class name="DomainObject.Employee,DomainObject" table="Employee">
       < id name="EmployeeId" column="Emp_ID" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
         < generator class="native">
          < /generator>
       < /id>
    < property name="EmployeePassword" column="EMP_PASSWORD" type="string"/>
    < property name="EmployeeName" column="EMP_NAME" type="string"/>
    < property name="TeamAssociatedWith" column="TEAM_ASSOCIATED_WITH" type="int"/>
    < property name="IsCaptain" column="IS_CAPTAIN" type="string"/>
    < property name="NumberOfMOM" column="NO_OF_MOM" type="int"/>
    < property name="Balance" column="BALANCE" type="int"/>
  < /class>

< sql-query name="selemployee" callable="true" >
    < return class="DomainObject.Employee,DomainObject">
      < return-property name="EmployeeId" column="Emp_ID"/>
      < return-property name="EmployeeName" column="EMP_NAME"/>
      < return-property name="EmployeePassword" column="EMP_PASSWORD"/>
      < return-property name="TeamAssociatedWith" column="TEAM_ASSOCIATED_WITH"/>
      < return-property name="IsCaptain" column="IS_CAPTAIN"/>
      < return-property name="NumberOfMOM" column="NO_OF_MOM"/>
      < return-property name="Balance" column="BALANCE"/>
    < /return>
    { ? = call GETPERSONTEST}
  < /sql-query>
< /hibernate-mapping>

**Stored Procedure Oracle**
create or replace PROCEDURE GETPERSONTEST(io_cursor out SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN io_cursor FOR  SELECT   EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_PASSWORD,TEAM_ASSOCIATED_WITH,IS_CAPTAIN,NO_OF_MOM,BALANCE  FROM employee  ;
END GETPERSONTEST;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

out ref cursor: yes.

Anything else: no.

See http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures

Comment: This is my Procedure in Oracle ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: create or replace procedure test(p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is begin open p_cursor FOR SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_PASSWORD,TEAM_ASSOCIATED_WITH,IS_CAPTAIN,NO_OF_MOM,BALANCE FROM employee ; end test; While calling it is throwing ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST'\nORA-06550

Comment: @anupam: add your mappings to the question

Comment: Updated question with mapping and store procedure in Oracle 10g

Comment: Thanks a lot now it is working fine.the way of calling was wrong it was {? = call GETPERSONTEST} which should be { call GETPERSONTEST }